# Zend 3 step layout and css/javascript including

Tags: php, html, zend-framework

I have a problem with Zend 3 step layout. Its working as it should be, but there is one problem i cant figur it out. I would like to have diferenet css and javascript links on diferent templates but since I prebuild layout for all templates I have to include css and javascript files to templates that dont really need it. I know I should just turn of 3 step layout but I would like to know if there is a different way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the code below to add a stylesheet in the view script rather than adding them all into the layout manually.

```
$this->headLink()->appendStylesheet('/css/stylesheet.css');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try code below:

```
$this->headScript()->appendFile('/js/jquery-ui.min.js'); 
$this->headLink()->appendStylesheet('/css/jquery-ui.min.css');
```